# What events happen reliably each season in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

If I am under siege, I understand that caravans, immigrants and emissaries will not arrive. What will I miss if I maintain a long siege through a whole season?
More especially, do any of those events happen during the winter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Migrants](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Immigrants) do have a chance to come in any season, so I guess that would be your main worry. People dieing decreases the chances anyway though.

A goblin [caravan](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Caravan) might come if you happen to have friendly goblins around. However, given the likelihood that that's a goblin siege, they wouldn't be sending one anyway.

If it's a season other than winter, you won't get a caravan, but the liaison will arrive after the siege is over. (Goblins don't send a liaison, btw.)

The only thing that I can think of besides caravans and migrants would be [crops](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/List_of_crops), but there aren't any winter-specific crops, so you should be good there too.